# Cloud Formation S3 bucket alias for static website issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I'm trying to create an static site in cloud formation using a bucket and an Alias type record, but I get the following error:

> Tried to create an alias that targets ., type A in zone Z7KQH4QJS55SO, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone

The zone Id (Z7KQH4QJS55SO) is from [Amazon Simple Storage Service Website Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_website_region_endpoints)

Here is the json for the Router 53 Record

```
"<Resource Id>": {
  "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
  "Properties": {
    "Comment": "...",
    "Name": {
      "Fn::Join": [
        "",
        [
          "subdomain",
          ".",
          "example.com",
          "."
        ]
      ]
    },
    "Type": "A",
    "AliasTarget": {
      "DNSName": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "<BucketName>",
          "DomainName"
        ]
      },
      "HostedZoneId": "Z7KQH4QJS55SO"
    },
    "HostedZoneId": {
      "Ref": "<HostedZoneResourceName>"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

It's a bit unintuitive, but the `DNSName` of `AliasTarget` should be just the regional S3 website endpoint, and not specific to the exact bucket you're pointing to.

Example, specific to the `sa-east-1` region:

```
  AliasTarget:
    DNSName: s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
    HostedZoneId: Z7KQH4QJS55SO
```

If you want your template to be region-agnostic, you could create a mapping in your template containing each region's S3 website endpoint and hosted zone ID and use `Fn::FindInMap` in your resource declarations.

Comment: Saved me a lot of time too. The docs are easy to misinterpret

Under "Amazon S3 bucket that is configured as a static website" at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-1.html#cfn-route53-aliastarget-dnshostname it says 
"Specify the domain name of the Amazon S3 website endpoint that you created the bucket in, for example, s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com."

The list of Hosted Zone IDs is available under "Amazon Simple Storage Service Website Endpoints" at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an alias create a CNAME record type and point it at:

```
"Fn::GetAtt": ["<BucketName>", "WebsiteURL"]
```

Comment: You probably meant `RegionalDomainName` and not `WebsiteURL` - the latter one is a URL and can't be used in a CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

The bit I missed with this when I got a similar error was setting the `ZoneId` to the *specific* value of `Z2FDTNDATAQYW2`.

Value checked correct at time of writing.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget.html

> HostedZoneId Alias resource records sets only: The value used depends
>   on where you want to route traffic:
>
> *Amazon API Gateway custom regional APIs and edge-optimized APIs*
>
> Specify the hosted zone ID for your API. You can get the applicable
>   value using the AWS CLI command get-domain-names:
>
> For regional APIs, specify the value of regionalHostedZoneId.
>
> For edge-optimized APIs, specify the value of
>   distributionHostedZoneId.
>
> *Amazon Virtual Private Cloud interface VPC endpoint*
>
> Specify the hosted
>   zone ID for your interface endpoint. You can get the value of
>   HostedZoneId using the AWS CLI command describe-vpc-endpoints.
>
> *CloudFront distribution*
>
> **Specify Z2FDTNDATAQYW2**.